# Symfony2 Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to entity Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, symfony-2.6

I got this error and I'm stuck since many hours

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Thinking\ThinkBundle\Entity\InYourMind::setThinkFriend() must be an instance of Thinking\ThinkBundle\Entity\InYourMindFriend, array given, called in /var/www/html/thinkroulette/vars/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 410 and defined
```

I searched for this issue and lots of results came up but I wasn't capable to solve this issue.

I'm trying to integrate two entities in one form and I got my idea form this post
[Create 2 different entities with same form in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217610/create-2-different-entities-with-same-form-in-symfony-2)

Probably it's a silliness but I couldn't understood even the error. :(

following a snipped of the main form

```
//InYourMindType.php
    class InYourMindType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('thinkFriend', new InYourMindFriendType)
        //...
```

This is the "embedded" form:

```
//InYourMindDriendType  
class InYourMindFriendType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => 'label_think_userEmail',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'title' => 'label_think_userEmail',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ));
        }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'thinkFriend';
    }
```

The twig where the main form is called (then the embedded one)

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(t_form.title) }}
    {{ form_widget(t_form.title) }}
    {{ form_errors(t_form.title) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(t_form.thinkFriend.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(t_form.thinkFriend.email) }}
    {{ form_errors(t_form.thinkFriend.email) }}
```

Those forms belong to two different entities connected respectively by a many-to-one and one-to-many relationship.

If you need i post the entities just ask.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set data_class option for your InYourMindFriendType

Checkout http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data-class

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it works, just another question. The field in the second form InYourMindFriendType isn't a mandatory one. If i don't fill any data, it pulls an error saying that it can't be null. If it were null, it wouldn't been saved into the table (related to that entity):
How can i do that? :)

Comment: You mean field 'email' in InYourMindFriendType. If it is, you should notice that option 'required' => false only disable HTML5 'required' attribute, If it throw error when 'email' is null, maybe there's a required constraint in your Entity Declaration